# Jquery Accordion Expand All Collapse All

Tags: jquery, accordion

I was looking for a way to include an "expand all" and "collapse all". I've updated the demo with the new code using a simple jquery accordion.

The original code should be credited to Ryan Stemkoski at http://www.stemkoski.com/stupid-simple-jquery-accordion-menu/

***Demo: http://jsbin.com/ucalu3/5/***

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.question').click(function() {

  if($(this).next().is(':hidden') != true) {
                $(this).removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).next().slideUp("normal");
  } else {
    $('.question').removeClass('active');  
     $('.answer').slideUp('normal');
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     }   
  }
   });

  $('.answer').hide();

  $('.expand').click(function(event)
    {$('.question').next().slideDown('normal');
        {$('.question').addClass('active');}
    }
  );

  $('.collapse').click(function(event)
    {$('.question').next().slideUp('normal');
        {$('.question').removeClass('active');}
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Just to point out, you don't need to edit the title to include 'Solved' once you get an answer. When an answer has been accepted, the answer count on the main page will turn from white to yellow to indicate that the problem is solved.

Comment: thanks to this question and answer... this saved me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a class or ID to the expand and collapse links then something like this will work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#expand").click(function(){
    ('.answer').slideDown('normal');
  });

  $("#collapse").click(function(){
    ('.answer').slideUp('normal');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be resolved much easier.

Simply use the jQuery hide/show command on the accordion element ('.ui-widget-content') you want to expand/collapse.

example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.expand').click(function() {
            $('.ui-widget-content').show();
        });
        $('.collapse').click(function() {
            $('.ui-widget-content').hide();
        });
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekelly/hG9b5/11/